# What is the correct package to use for SIgnalR with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm trying to use SignalR in an ASP.NET Core web application but I'm struggling to find the correct package to use. In [this article](https://radu-matei.github.io/blog/signalr-core/), they say to use "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" (with the help of a NuGet.Config file) but when I do a `dotnet restore`, I get:

```
error NU1102: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server with version (>= 0.2.0)
error NU1102:   - Found 1 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 0.0.1-alpha ]
error NU1102:   - Found 0 version(s) in aspnetcidev
```

I guess the v0.0.1-alpha is not the one I want.

However, I found the package "Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server" and it seems to work but the last published version is from November 2016... That, and the namespace make me think that it's not the package I have to use neither...

I also saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TrttIkbs6c&t=2125s) that refers to the v1.0.0 version but, of course, I can get it to work...

Anyway, what is the correct package to use in order to use SignalR?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server is an obsolete package that will not be shipped. For the server you need to install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR package from the https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json feed

Comment: As long as the dev version is alpha and no documentation is around it might be better to stick with the one from aspnetmaster for now: https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the prerelease dev package for now.

https://dotnet.myget.org/F/aspnetcore-ci-dev/api/v3/index.json (thank you Pawel)

I also had to get the Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives from there.

**Update**:
I had to go back to .NET core 1.1 packages since migrating to 2.0 will not work for several reasons. I went back to using the unmaintained Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server Version **0.1.0** from here:
https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetmaster/api/v3/index.json

**Update**:
For a new project I'm successfully using the **v.1.0.0-alpha2-final** version from nugget.org.
Examples including the JavaScript files can be found here: [aspnet/SignalR-samples](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples)

[image: Visual Studio 2017 NuGet Package Manager steps]